# Quote update error

Tags: magento-enterprise, quote

I was trying to update a quote item quantity programtically; but, it constantly throws an error "The requested quantity for". Can anybody please provide assistance to resolve this issue ? code follows:

```
$buyInfo = array(
    'qty' => 102,
    "super_attribute"=>array(175=>19)
);
$this->_quote->updateItem($quoteItemId, new Varien_Object($buyInfo))->save();

$this->_quote - Quote Object
```

$quoteItemId  - Item Id
Current quantity of the product in the quote: 100

Total stock of the product:150

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Your Total qty for product is 150 and 100 is already added in quote so
>   items available to add in quote is only 50 and you are trying to add
>   102

if your "super_attribute"=>array(175=>19) are not same as added in current quote it will add new item in quote.

Comment: :I had added the same super attributes to the quote.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(3);
 $buyInfo = array(
    'qty' => 100,
    "super_attribute"=>array(175=>19)
);
$this->_quote->addProduct($product , new Varien_Object($buyInfo))->save();

Comment: I want just update the quantity from 100 to 102 in cart. Thanks!

Comment: method updateItem() is adding old item + new item so it will be 100+102 = 202

Comment: if ($resultItem->compare($item)) {  
                        // Product configuration is same as in other quote item  
                        $resultItem->setQty($resultItem->getQty() + $item->getQty());  
                        $this->removeItem($item->getId());  
                        break;  
                    }  
This is the case in updateItem() method

Answer (score 0):

Yes, got it!

```
   $parentItem = $item->getParentItem() ?: $item; //Set quantity for parent item

$parentItem->setQty(102)->save();
```

It was that much simple :)